# Uploading image with Volley liabrary. Android side code issue.

Tags: android, android-volley

I am uploading this image using volley library. when i test on postman the php file is working properly. Whats wrong with the code in android then

I am clicking the image from take picture button and then submitting it on submit click.

here is the entire code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private Button image_selector, submit;
TextView image;
String encoded_string, image_name = "image 1.jpg";
Bitmap bitmap;
File file;
String fileUrl = "http://192.168.2.8/image-upload-android/image-upload.php";
ImageView image_clicked;

Uri file_uri;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image_selector = (Button)findViewById(R.id.image_select);
    submit =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    image = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.image_name);
    image_clicked = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_clicked);

    image_selector.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            getFileUr();
            image.setText(image_name);

            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file_uri);
            startActivityForResult(i, 10);
        }
    });

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new Encode_image().execute();
        }
    });

}

private void getFileUr() {


    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+
     file.separator+ image_name);
    file_uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

    }
}



private class Encode_image extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_uri.getPath());

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

        byte[] array = stream.toByteArray();

        encoded_string = Base64.encodeToString(array,0);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        makeRequest();
    }
}

private void makeRequest() {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, fileUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        if(jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")){

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success: "+jsonObject.getString("success"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: "+jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("encoded_string",encoded_string);
            map.put("image_name",image_name);

            return  map;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(request);

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Android Networking](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Networking) . I have created this library that is having all feature that is missing in volley.

```
AndroidNetworking.upload(url)
                 .addMultipartFile("image", new File(imagePath))   
                 .setTag("uploadTest")
                 .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                 .build()
                 .setUploadProgressListener(new UploadProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(long bytesUploaded, long totalBytes) {
                    // do anything with progress 
                    }
                 })
                 .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // do anything with response                
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError error) {
                    // handle error 
                    }
                 });
```